# Why does unsubscribe() take so much time?

Tags: angular, forms, performance, rxjs

I try to detect performance problem in my angular application. When user starts typing something in form input (form is reactive) then chars will appear very slowly. This is how my component looks like.

```
 <my-message [selectedFeedObj]="selectedFeedObj"
                             [offFocus]="isClickable || showShareList"
                             [selectedThread]="selectedThread"
                             [person]="person"
                             [showAnswer]="showAnswer"></my-message>
```

in profile data I see the following:

[image]

as far as I understand it means that clearTimeout callback takes a lot of time of execution. Probably, if I remove this unsubscribe from async observable performance will be much better.

Answer (score 2):

it's very possible that you are using functions in your component template. get rid of functions and your performance issues will be solved.